# How to get Centroid in GeoPandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

**Centroid in Geopandas**

I have two location so I want get centroid from geopandas by python? How I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you're trying to calculate the centroid of a set of points, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088232/calculate-centroid-of-entire-geodataframe-of-points/70088741#70088741

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid.html):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")
df["centroid"] = df["geometry"].centroid
df
```

See also [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)'s documentation: [`object.centroid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.centroid).